# Loading image with XHR without responseType set to blob

Tags: javascript, image, xmlhttprequest

I have this situation in which I load an image with XMLHttpRequest but without setting responseType to blob. So I receive a string

[image]

My question is, is it still possible to render the image in this situation?

I tried, for example, to convert this string to a Blob

```
out = new Blob([imageString],  { type: 'image/png' });
```

but this doesn't render the expected image. Any suggestions?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/convert-image-url-to-base64-l6h8hn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

And here is how my node backend sends that image to the browser

```
app.get("/binary/*", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  const file = binaryPath + '/test.jpg';
  res.sendFile(file);
});
```

Comment: Is it maybe a different image format, such as `out = new Blob([imageString],  { type: 'image\/jpeg' });` ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: In my application I get a binary image via websocket and then render it via `blob = new Blob([data], {'type': 'image\/jpeg'}); url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);` and set the `<img src=url>`. That works. Are you sure your `imageString` is a binary string? You could check whether `btoa(imageString)` gives a correct base64 encoded image ...

Comment: Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/convert-image-url-to-base64-l6h8hn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts As you can see it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I did some experiemnts using different encodings without success. So my best guess is that the problem is due to this warning in the console: `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value blob`. Here is some input you might want to consider: https://roufid.com/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-url-value-angular/

Comment: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/convert-image-url-to-base64-wk98y6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsafe-html.pipe.ts) is a demo without that error. The result is the same unfortunately. I've also add a snippet with the backend code, which sends the image to the browser (express/nodejs)

Comment: I am not very good at TypeScript - maybe you can check where the result of `(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` is assigned to the component's `src` data attribute? I only could identify `this.src = dataUrl;` which is the external https url, I think.

Comment: yes, the output of `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` is send back via the callback and assigned to `this.src`

Comment: What makes me wondering is that `console.log(dataUrl);` does not print the `createObjectURL` but the http url ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it: If you do not want to have `xhr.responseType = 'blob'` and you want to create a url from received data, then you need to set `xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'`. This allows to convert the binary `xhr.response` into a blob and then create a `URL.createObjectURL`.

The point is that when you do not set `responseType` to a binary type then you get the default `xhr.responseType = 'text'` and utf8 encoding. And then blob creation fails.

I have included this solution in your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/convert-image-url-to-base64-l6h8hn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: I think you're right. But somehow I would expect that it should be possible to convert a binary string to a Blob or ObjectURL. But anyway, as long as this is not proven, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: I tried many different ways to decode the utf8 string into a binary arrayBuffer format that allows converting into a blob - without success so far.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the data is being decoded as ASCII when you don't specify a responseType. So for every character greater than 127, you get a 253, thus the image gets corrupted. To avoid this add `overrideMimeType` with `charset=x-user-defined`.

```
const client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.overrideMimeType('image/jpeg; charset=x-user-defined');
  client.open("GET", binaryPath + '/test.jpg', false);
  client.send();
  const blob = new Blob(
    [Uint8Array.from(client.response, c => c.charCodeAt(0)).buffer],
    { type: "image/jpeg" });
```